# GetOrgChart - Mixed orientation in the same orgchart

Tags: getorgchart

I've been playing around with GetOrgChart and have read all the demo html files on how to personalize the chart, as well as all the the documentation on the 8 types of orientations. But, I was unable to accomplish what I am after.

What I believe I need to do is to use 2 types of orientations in the same OrgChart as in my company, we have more than 230 people under 3 directors. If I only expand to the 2nd level, the organisation chart is impossible to read as a result. So to fix it, I want to have all the odd numbered levels in one type of orientation, or something similar to that:

http://www.basicprimitives.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=122&lang=en

Is what I am saying even possible with GetOrgChart? If so, please explain how it can be done.

Apologies if my English isn't great.

Comment: The current version does not support mixed orientation

Answer (score 0):

Actually GetORgChart supports mixed Hierarchy
[image]

Here is the demo: http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos/Mixed-Hierarchy